# Getting USB to VGA to work on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, graphics, vga, gpu-driver

I recently purchased [this](http://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/slim-usb-3-vga-adapter~USB32VGAES) USB to VGA adapter for the third monitor I had and it works great with Windows along side the driver it had for it. However on Linux I can't seem to get it to work. I searched their website and couldn't seem to find a driver but it is recognized with lsusb. So I was wondering if anyone had any ideas about how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug on [Lauchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1216006) concerning this hardware.  If you add your contact details as well, it'll get higher priority because it will affect multiple users...

Comment: I'll have I'll have to do that, just out of curiosity you don't happen to know if this is a Ubuntu only bug?

Comment: All of Linux!  It's a kernel problem...